# Whats the proper way to copy data from an io.Reader directly to a destination bytes.Buffer in golang?

Tags: go

I have code that wants to copy data from an io.Reader directly to a bytes.Buffer struct which is intended to stay around in memory as a cache. Right now I'm just calling `io.Copy(dstBytesBuffer, reader)`. But looking at the io.Copy code it looks like it is creating a buffer itself and copying data from the reader into this buffer, and then writing from that buffer to my dstBytesBuffer. Is there a way to skip that and just have it copy straight from reader to my destination buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`io.Copy()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy) for this is perfectly fine. `io.Copy()` is "optimized" for several use cases. Quoting from its doc:

> Copy copies from src to dst until either EOF is reached on src or an error occurs. It returns the number of bytes copied and the first error encountered while copying, if any.
>
> A successful Copy returns err == nil, not err == EOF. Because Copy is defined to read from src until EOF, it does not treat an EOF from Read as an error to be reported.
>
> **If src implements the WriterTo interface, the copy is implemented by calling src.WriteTo(dst). Otherwise, if dst implements the ReaderFrom interface, the copy is implemented by calling dst.ReadFrom(src).**

Without knowing anything from your source [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader), even if it doesn't provide an efficient `WriteTo(dst)` method, we surely know your destination is a [`bytes.Buffer`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes) and it implements [`io.ReaderFrom`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReaderFrom) as it has a [`Buffer.ReadFrom()`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer.ReadFrom) method which reads from the given `io.Reader` without creating or using additional buffers.

Comment: Ah ok thank you! Yeah the io.Reader is an io.PipeReader.